# ALERT com inputs text e checkbox - IONIC 3

Tags: typescript, ionic3

Olá, Preciso criar em um componente AlertController com uma lista de checkboxs e um campo de texto , igual no código abaixo

```
alert.setTitle('Registrar item ? ' + p.descricao_resumida);
        for (let course of this.obs_preparo) {
          console.log(course.observacao)
          alert.addInput({
            type: 'checkbox',
            label: course.observacao,
            value: course.id
          });
        }
        alert.addInput({
          type: 'text',
          name: 'quantidade',
          value: '1',
        });
```

Mas quando é exibido, aparece o campo de texto no formato checkbox, Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

Na documentação oficial encontrada [nesse link](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/components/alert/AlertController/#alert-inputs) diz o seguinte:

> (...) Radios, checkboxes and text inputs are all accepted, but they cannot be mixed. For example, an alert could have all radio button inputs, or all checkbox inputs, but the same alert cannot mix radio and checkbox inputs. (...)

Traduzindo, significa que `Alerts` não podem possuir tipos de `input` diferentes. Então utilizar um `checkbox` e um `text input` não é permitido, essa é uma limitação do próprio componente. Note que, tipos diferentes de `input` não signifique que você não possa ter dois `inputs` de texto do tipo `tel` ou `number`, nesse caso é permitido.

A documentação oficial te sugere criar uma `modal` própria no lugar para fazer o que você quer.